# pyqt signal from a window not changing the main window widgets

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I can pass values between two windows using signal,
and I want the plain text change, while I press a button from another window.
but the insertPlainText and even text.show() are not working

I've tried sending the signal to the init part of the Mainwindow,
tried update, repaint, but none of them works.

appreciate for any of your help, thanks!

---

the search_send method in class SearchWindow to MainWindow method test_

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.tag_box.hide()

    def test_(self, i): # -------problem here------------------
        print(i)  // <- value here were right
        self.ui.tag_box.insertPlainText(i)  # -------Plain Text does not change-------
        self.ui.tag_box.show()# -------Plain Text does not show either--------------


class SearchWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    signal=pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, endpoint=None, user=None, password=None, points_link=None):
        super(SearchWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Search()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.search_send)

    def search_send(self): # -------problem here------------------
        tag_list = [tag1,tag2, tag3]
        otherClass = MainWindow()
        self.signal.connect(otherClass.test_)
        for k in tag_list:
            self.signal.emit(k)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick sorry, updated

Comment: That double backslash messes up when copy-pasted. And thanks for update.

Comment: This is not a mre. For starters, you haven't posted the contents of `Ui_Dialog` nor of `Ui_Search`. Also, you don't show how the search window is created. i.e. is it created when the user pushes a button? Anyway, the issue with your code is that in `SearchWindow.search_send` you are creating a second instance of `MainWindow` (which isn't shown) and connecting the signal to the slot of this second instance instead of the original one that is showing. You need to connect the signal to the slot of `window`. How to do this depends on how the search window is created/managed.

Comment: @Heike Sorry for not posting the ui contents, I thought I was stuck in a basic concept, somebody may figure out without compiling my code, and then you came, you did solve my problem, by changing the MainWindow() to window , it worked well, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

As we're unclear what `Ui_Dialog` contains, I can't tell what's wrong exactly, but can show you how *Signal* should be used.

This is example of `Signal` that's transferring text to `Slot`. Name may differ in *PyQt5* - change accordingly.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot
import sys


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    sig = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.text = QTextEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.text.textChanged.connect(self.onChange)

    def onChange(self):
        self.sig.emit(self.text.toPlainText())


class SubWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, connect_target: MainWindow):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sub")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        connect_target.sig.connect(self.onSignal)

    @Slot(str)
    def onSignal(self, text):
        self.text.insertPlainText(text + '\r\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    window_sub = SubWindow(window)
    window_sub.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Anything inside *Main* will be *inserted* to *QPlainTextEdit* as you wanted.

[image]

Comment: It turns out I am using the wrong slot to receive the signal, thanks for your reply